# PHPMailer HTML not rendering

Tags: phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send HTML emails.  It sends the emails fine, but the HTML does not render in the email clients.  I've tested this with web-based GMail and OSX mail.app IMAP'ed to the same GMail account.  Neither render properly.

I'm pulling my hair out to solve this.  Any ideas???

PHP Code to format the email to send (the emails get sent so that is working):

```
// mail format settings
// $mail->WordWrap = 50;        // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);            // set email format to HTML
$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";         // set the charset to UTF-8
$mail->Encoding = '7bit';
$body = '';
$body .= "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">";
$body .= "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\">";
$body .= "<head>";
$body .= "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />";
$body .= "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Language\" content=\"en-us\" />";
$body .= "<style>";
$body .= "body {font-family:\"trebuchet ms\", arial, \"san serif\";font-size:14px;}";
$body .= ".email-header{ margin:5px;padding:20px;background:#dddddd;border-radius:10px;color:#000000;font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;}";
$body .= ".email-body{margin:10px 20px;}";
$body .= "</style>";
$body .= "</head>";
$body .= "<body>"; 
if ($_POST["type"]=='confirmation') {

    // set the email body
    $body .= "<div class=\"email-header\">Sky Lodge HOA Reservation Confirmation</div>";
    $body .= "<div class=\"email-body\">";
    $body .= "Dear ". $_POST["name"] . ",<br/><br/>";
    $body .= "This email is confirming your reservation for unit nnn x:<br/>";
    $body .= "<strong>Arriving:</strong> date<br/>";
    $body .= "<strong>Departing:</strong> date<br/><br/>"; 
    $body .= "Please click here to view your existing reservation(s):<br/>";
    $body .= "http://www.somesite.com/index.php?token=" . $_POST["token"] . "<br/><br/>";

    // set the email subject
    $mail->Subject = "Sky Lodge HOA: Reservation Confirmation";

} else if ($_POST["type"]=='notify') {

    // set the email body
    $body .= "<div class=\"email-header\">Sky Lodge HOA Attention Required</div>";
    $body .= "<div class\"email-body\">";
    $body .= "Dear ". $_POST["name"] . ",<br/><br/>";
    $body .= "It is your turn to make a reservation for unit nnn x.<br/><br/>";
    $body .= "Please click here to make your reservation:<br/>";
    $body .= "http://www.somesite.com/index.php?token=" . $_POST["token"] . "<br/><br/>";

    // set the email subject
    $mail->Subject = "Sky Lodge HOA: Attention Required";

}
$body .= "Thank You,<br/>Patti Rea";
$body .= "</div>";
$body .= "</body>";
$body .= "</html>";
echo('$body: ' . $body);
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";
```

Resulting mail:

```
Return-Path: <darren@theehlers.org>
Received: from skylodge (c-174-52-123-157.hsd1.ut.comcast.net. [174.52.123.157])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ko12sm7817099pbb.52.2012.02.29.11.02.07
        (version=SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Wed, 29 Feb 2012 11:02:07 -0800 (PST)
Date: Wed, 29 Feb 2012 12:02:05 -0700
Return-Path: darren@theehlers.org
To: Sky Lodge <darren@theehlers.org>
From: Darren Ehlers <darren@theehlers.org>
Cc: kathi@theehlers.org
Reply-To: Darren Ehlers <darren@theehlers.org>
Subject: Sky Lodge HOA: Reservation Confirmation
Message-ID: <9941ff8576a1763200e134b5b313b1b1@skylodge>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.1 (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_9941ff8576a1763200e134b5b313b1b1"


--b1_9941ff8576a1763200e134b5b313b1b1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients


--b1_9941ff8576a1763200e134b5b313b1b1
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
<style>
body {font-family:"trebuchet ms", arial, "san serif";font-size:14px;}
.email-header{ margin:5px;padding:20px;background:#dddddd;border-radius:10px;color:#000000;font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;}
.email-body{margin:10px 20px;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="email-header">Sky Lodge HOA Reservation Confirmation</div>
<div class="email-body">
Dear Sky Lodge,<br/><br/>
This email is confirming your reservation for unit nnn x:<br/>
<strong>Arriving:</strong> date<br/>
<strong>Departing:</strong> date<br/><br/>
Please click here to view your existing reservation(s):<br/>
http://www.somesite.com/index.php?token=WQ85o7OiT9<br/><br/>
Thank You,<br/>
Patti Rea
</div>
</body>
</html>

--b1_9941ff8576a1763200e134b5b313b1b1--
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested by removing the doctype and header tags... In my opinion there is no need for them... The rest looks fine.